# Windows doesn't boot after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, windows, asus, gpt

I have had serious problems installing Ubuntu and Windows and have dual boot. Recently I installed both operating systems, Ubuntu was the last one, and after that my computer was booting directly to Windows 7. I used my Ubuntu USB live to repair the grub, and could repair. Now I initiate my pc with grub 1.99 and Ubuntu and Windows are recognized, but Windows gives an error and don't initiate, suggesting to use Windows DVD to repair the grub. I tried that but with no effects on be behavior.

I have a new asus n56vm. This conflicts with gpt and mbr have been a huge pain to me. I don't know what to to, I installed Ubuntu and Windows numerous times since I bought this computer 2 weeks ago.

Comment: What error did Windows give?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have installed Ubuntu and Windows lot of times since you bought the laptop my solution might make you install it once more. What you are facing is a problem related to UEFI.

**I am assuming that using UEFI or GPT isn't very important to you.** So this is how you can get both Ubuntu and Windows to work on your system :

1. Go into BIOS and **disable UEFI**. Save settings and restart and go into BIOS again
2. If somewhere there is a setting to delete boot options then delete
   all the boot options. Though I am pretty sure that you cannot delete
   CD/DVD from boot option but if you can then **don't** do it. Save
   all settings and restart and go into BIOS again.
3. Put your windows DVD in the drive
4. Somewhere (mostly on the last tab of your BIOS) you will find an
   option for boot override. Select your DVD drive and press enter.
   Remember that this boot over ride option should **NOT** have UEFI
   in it's name.
5. You will now boot from windows DVD through BIOS in non-UEFI mode.
6. During windows installation select "custom install" and then delete
   all existing partitions on your harddisk. Create partition for
   windows. When creating this partition windows will automatically
   make another small partition of about 100MB size as system reserved.
   Leave the rest of the unallocated space for now. We will take care
   of that space while installing Ubuntu.
7. Once windows installation is done put your Ubuntu CD in the drive
   and boot from it again
8. During installation of Ubuntu select the option "do something else"
   and create a primary partition for Ubuntu.
9. Now after creating partition for Ubuntu click on the rest of the
   unallocated space and click on create new partition again. But this
   time slected **extended partition**
10. Once you create extended partition you see that all your
     unallocated space is being shown under that unallocated partition
     in a sub menu. In this unallocated space you make rest of your
     partitions like linux-swap (necessary for linux to work efficiently
     and for hibernate to work correctly) and other partitions for your
     data.
11. Make sure that the bootloader device is **sda** without any partition
     number after it.
12. Proceed with installation. If everything goes well you should be
     successfully dual booting in both Ubuntu and Windows

Note 1 : If you do not use a USB drive to boot instead of DVD drive then follow the same steps and just use USB drive each time while booting from BIOS.
Note 1 : If using UEFI and GPT is important to you then you might want to follow this guide : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling grub can perhaps resolve the trick

1. Start with Ubuntu USB Live
2. Open a terminal then switch in chroot mode, by example:

   > ```
   > mount -t ext4 /dev/sda /mnt/tmp   
   > mount -t proc none /mnt/tmp/proc
   > mount -o bind /dev /mnt/tmp/dev
   > chroot /mnt/tmp /bin/bash
   > ```
3. Execute `grub-install /dev/sda`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just access Windows and don't have time for any of the above, try using [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/). It allows to boot a partition directly by just booting from the disk. It's an invaluable toolkit too!

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the OP's question?